# How to add a MapRoute like example.com/id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I want to create a URLs shortener website. URLs that I offer are like `example.com/XXX` where
`XXX` is the value of the short URL.

I want to have website on `example.com` and URLs are `example.com/xxx`. I want to get `xxx` from URL and redirect users to equivalent URLs in database.

How can implement this?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new route in your RouteConfig for example:

```
 public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute("empty",
                            "{id}",
                            new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
                );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
    }
```

And the simply go to your database with the id passed in the index

```
  public ActionResult Index(int id)
  {
        //Do Stuff with db
        return View();
  }
```

asp.net mvc documentation [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs).

Answer (score 1):

One way you be doing the needed redirection in the default controller action. By default in asp.net mvc it is home/index.

So in the index action you should be having such code

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
      var url = Db.GetNeededUrl(id);
      return Redirect(url);
}
```

So now if the user enters such an address site.com/NewYear  you'll get redirected to the equivalent url that is in you database.